# Cannot create an “insert row” step in an Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm creating a Azure Logic App that uses SQL. When I try to insert a row, I get a disabled <kbd>Create</kbd> button. Why? What is wrong with my input?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To create MySqL connection in logic app ,you need to pass the on-prem gateway connection Name as well in order to create a api connection as shown in the below screen shot.

[image]

You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install) documentation to install on-prem gateway for logic apps.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you